# Firestore Listener Crashes Unity App On Android, but works fine in the Unity editor. How do I solve this?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, crash

Any help would be really appreciated.

**The Crash**
My Unity app uses Firebase Firestore listeners to receive data. In the Unity editor everything works very well and I never get an error. I built to my Android device (Pixel 2), but there it crashes about a second after startup.

I looked at Android Logcat and noticed that the last thing it did was receive a callback from Firestore:

```
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity Received Public Projects Query Callback. No pending writes, so we can update the Projects. Documents: 2
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity ArchViewer.<>c:<ListenToPublicProjects>b__67_0(QuerySnapshot)
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity System.Action`1:Invoke(T)
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity Firebase.Firestore.<Listen>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity System.Func`1:Invoke()
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity System.Action`3:Invoke(T1, T2, T3)
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity Firebase.Firestore.Query:QuerySnapshotsHandler(Int32, IntPtr, FirestoreError, String)
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:PollCallbacks()
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
2021/02/10 17:45:17.898 26111 26146 Info Unity
```

After that the fatal error(s) happens:

```
2021/02/10 17:45:17.908 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: mid == null
2021/02/10 17:45:17.908 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe java_vm_ext.cc:577]     in call to CallObjectMethodV
2021/02/10 17:45:17.908 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe java_vm_ext.cc:577]     from boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender()
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting...
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655] All threads:
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (46):
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=7 Runnable
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x132c0228 self=0x7937c4f010
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=26122 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x77b45eed00
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   | state=R schedstat=( 67570784 10588910 215 ) utm=4 stm=1 core=6 HZ=100
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0x77b44f0000-0x77b44f2000 stackSize=1023KB
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00000000004a53f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+140)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 00000000005b42b4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+372)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 00000000005d1854  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+924)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 00000000005b5220  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::RunCheckpointFunction()+176)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 0000000000346168  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+1312)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 00000000005d2814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+108)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 00000000005d22f8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+192)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #07 pc 00000000000b0758  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   native: #08 pc 0000000000050150  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
2021/02/10 17:45:18.122 26111 26146 Fatal igns.ArchViewe runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
```

And that goes on for another 2700 lines... Don't even know which section to look at.

The code that sets up the Firestore listener (but don't think the problem is in the code as it works fine in the Unity editor):

```
public static ListenerRegistration ListenToPublicProjects(Timestamp LastModified)
        {
            Query queryRef = database.Collection(ProjectsCollection).WhereEqualTo(ProjectTypeField, 1)
                .WhereGreaterThan(LastModifiedField, LastModified);

            ListenerRegistration listener = queryRef.Listen(snapshot =>
            {
                if (snapshot.Metadata.HasPendingWrites)
                {   Debug.Log("Received Public Projects Query Callback. Still waiting for pending writes before we can update the Projects..."); return; }
                else
                    Debug.Log("Received Public Projects Query Callback. No pending writes, so we can update the Projects. Documents: " + snapshot.Count);

                if (snapshot.Count == 0)
                {   Debug.Log("Public Projects Query is empty"); return; }


                foreach (DocumentChange change in snapshot.GetChanges())
                {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = change.Document;
                    ArchProjectData projectData = ArchProjectData.FromDictionary(document.ToDictionary());
                    ArchProject project = AssemblyManager.CreateProject(projectData);

                    if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Added)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(String.Format("New public project: {0}", change.Document.Id));
                        ReferenceManager.AddProject(project, ProjectList.PublicProjects);
                    }
                    else if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Modified)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(String.Format("Modified public project: {0}", change.Document.Id));
                        ReferenceManager.UpdateProject(project, ProjectList.PublicProjects);
                    }
                    else if (change.ChangeType == DocumentChange.Type.Removed)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(String.Format("Removed public project: {0}", change.Document.Id));
                        ReferenceManager.RemoveProject(project, ProjectList.PublicProjects);
                    }
                }

                OnPublicProjectsReceived?.Invoke();
            });
            return listener;
        }
```

**Background info**
Unity version: 2020.2.3
Firebase SDK version: 7.0.2
Android version: 11

Because of this crash I decided to completely rebuild my project from scratch to make sure nothing else was interfering, but it still happened. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Firestore for games is in beta. Even though it's been "out" for Android and iOS for some time, since there is JNI in your call stack there's a good chance that it's the beta games layer that caused an issue. Since they really want to get Firestore to gold ASAP, the team is super active on GitHub and you should definitely ask again there: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/labels/api%3A%20firestore

Comment: With all that said, and since it's Android specific, I wonder if there's any funkiness around CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync. Are you `await`'ing or running this in a continuation (ex FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync.ContinueWithOnMainThread(task=>{/*cool stuff here*/}); ) or ensuring that you wait in any other way before running this code?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for you reply! I will post my question on Github next.

Comment: I am `await` ing the CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync. It is definitely done with the CheckAndFixDependencies, because after that I initialize my FirestoreManager, which is needed to send out the Listener.

Comment: I've pinpointed where the issue occurs and it happens when callling change.ChangeType

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred when calling `change.ChangeType`. I found a workaround for it here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/889#issuecomment-745695182

This is the work around code:

```
public DocumentChange.Type GetChangeType(DocumentChange change) {
  if (change.OldIndex < 0) {
    return DocumentChange.Type.Added;
  } else if (change.NewIndex < 0) {
    return DocumentChange.Type.Removed;
  } else {
    return DocumentChange.Type.Modified;
  }
}
```